# Какой callback использовать чтобы был доступ к id несохраненной записи

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть метод в модели:

```
def set_hash
 unless self.api_key
   self.api_key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest ("shop_" + self.id.to_s)
   self.save!
 end
end
```

и `before_save :set_hash`,
но это не работает, т.к. судя по всему self.id = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не рекомендовал использовать коллбэки вообще и для конкретной задачи в частности.
Ими слишком трудно управлять.
Если, всё же, использовать коллбэк, то в данном случае может подойти `after_create`. На момент его вызова у модели уже будет `id` и, в отличии от `after_save` он не будет вызываться всякий раз при сохранении записи. В третьих рельсах, помнится, был запрещён вызов `save` из коллбэков, вызываемых после сохранения (чтобы избежать зацикливаний)

Однако, я бы лучше определил метод `api_key`:

```
def api_key
  @api_key ||= Digest::SHA1.hexdigest ("shop_#{self.id}")
end
```

Это позволит не хранить избыточные данные в БД. В случае, если по `api_key` нужно осуществлять поиск, лучше реализовать отдельный `SearchObject`.

Рекомендую по теме [`Growing Rails Applications in Practice`](http://leanpub.com/growing-rails)

Comment: В моем случае проблема была в условии.

Answer (score 0):

Коллбэк `before_save` срабатывает перед сохранением, когда `id` еще нет, более того сохранять в этом коллбэке модель смысла нет, так как после этого события пойдет `save`. Вам лучше использовать не `before_save`, а `after_save`, когда в модели будет уже идентификатор `id`.